# Line function from Fritz John's article.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading a Fritz John's article on ultrahyperbolic PDE, and I am little bit puzzled as to what is a line function.

He states, that since $v$ is a line function then: 
$$v(\theta \xi +(1-\theta)\eta , \eta) = v(\xi , \theta \eta+(1-\theta)\xi)=v(\xi ,\eta)$$

where $\xi = (\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3) \ \eta=(\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3)$.

Now what in this context does line function mean, so that I could infer the same identities?

The paper is here:
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077490637

It's on page 303, equation (8).

Edit:
I added to Ant's request the information for $v(\xi ,\eta)$.

"If $v$ is defined by ($(6)v(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3)=(\sum_i (\frac{q_i}{q_3})^2)^{1/2}u(\frac{p_2+q_2}{q_3},\frac{-p_1-q_1}{q_3},\frac{p_2-q_2}{q_3},\frac{q_1-p_1}{q_3})$ where $u$ satisifies the PDE: $u_{x_1x_1}+u_{x_2x_2} = u_{x_3x_3}+u_{x_4x_4}$, and $p_i=\xi_j \eta_k - \xi_k \eta_j$ and for any cyclic permutation of $i,j,k \in \{ 1,2,3\}$, and $q_i=\xi_i -\eta_i$.), it obviously depends on on the line through $\xi$ and $\eta$.
The fact that $v$ is a line function implies that for every $\theta$:
$$v(\theta \xi + (1-\theta)\eta , \eta ) = v(\xi , \theta \eta +(1-\theta)\xi)=v(\xi ,\eta)$$
"

Comment: It would probably help to provide the relevant passage, as right now the article is beyond a paywall :)

Comment: @Ant I added the relvant information for answering my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not stated what the allowed range of $\theta$ is. In the following I'm assuming it is ${\mathbb R}\setminus\{0\}$. We are given a function
$$v:\quad {\mathbb R}^3\times{\mathbb R}^3\setminus D, \quad (\xi,\eta)\mapsto v(\xi,\eta)\qquad(\xi\ne\eta)\ ,$$
where $D:=\{(x,x)\>|\>x\in{\mathbb R}^3\}$ is the diagonal. This function has the following property: For any two point pairs $(\xi,\eta)$, $(\xi',\eta')$ on the same line $\ell\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ one has $v(\xi,\eta)=v(\xi',\eta')$.

*Proof:* Consider a line $\ell$ and two different points $\xi$, $\eta\in\ell$. Then
$$\theta\mapsto x(\theta):=(1-\theta)\xi+\theta\eta\qquad(-\infty<\theta<\infty)$$ 
is nothing else but a parametrization of $\ell$ with $x(0)=\xi$, $x(1)=\eta$. Your second identity says that $$v\bigl(\xi, x(\theta)\bigr)=v(\xi,\eta\bigr)\quad\forall\>\theta\ne0\ .$$ Therefore we can fix $\xi$ and move $\eta$ on $\ell$ without changing the value of $v$. In the same way (using the first identity) the value of $v$ does not change when we  fix $\eta$ and move $\xi$ along $\ell$.  Doing two such movements in a row we can connect any pair $\{\xi,\eta\}\subset\ell$ with any other pair $\{\xi',\eta'\}\subset\ell$: $$v(\xi,\eta)=v(\xi',\eta)=v(\xi',\eta')\ .$$
All in all we can say the following: Let $L$ be the set of all lines $\ell\subset{\mathbb R}^3$. Your identities imply that there is a function
$$g:\quad L\to{\mathbb R},\qquad \ell\mapsto g(\ell)$$
such that
$$v(\xi,\eta)=g(\xi\vee\eta)\qquad\forall\  \xi\ne\eta\ .$$

Comment: Christian, is there a way to show what you wrote through equations?; that would help, cause at the moment it seems to me be a little bit like hand waving explanation.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that a line function is a function $v$ inputting two parameters $\in \mathbb{R}^3$. It's a notion that I agree with, intuitively. However, John's 1938 paper also calls $u$, inputting four real parameters, a line function; not only in the head of section 1 ("Interpretation of u as a line function"); but in particular, on page 301 pretty much near the middle: "If the line function $u$ is a solution of (2), [...] We call a line function $u$ with the latter property [...]". So I fear the definition (or its use) of a line function is a little vague.